# Using Windows.Automation, can I locate an AutomationElement by regex?

Tags: c#, windows, automation, ui-automation, automationelement

I have an object tree that has row objects within a table parent. I'm attempting to put all these rows into an `AutomationElementCollection`

```
AutomationElementCollection asdf = ParentTableObj.FindAll
     (
     TreeScope.Children,
     new PropertyCondition
          (
          AutomationElement.NameProperty,
          "I want to use regex here"
          )
     );
```

All of the rows' `AutomationElement.NameProperty` contains the string "row". However, they are variations of that string - e.g. "Row1", "Row2", "TopRow", ...

It seems like I may be missing something since the `FindAll` method allows you to define the `TreeScope` and find any `AutomationElement`, which matches the provided `Condition` parameter. I just want my condition to be unrestricted since I can already control the find scope by `TreeScope`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Example :
AutomationElement element = FindFirstDescendant( 
    AutomationElement.FromHandle(windows_hWnd), 
    (ele)=>Regex.IsMatch( ele.Current.Name, pattern)
);

//The generic method to find a descendant element:
public static AutomationElement FindFirstDescendant(AutomationElement element, Func<AutomationElement, bool> condition) {
    var walker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
    element = walker.GetFirstChild(element);
    while (element != null) {
        if (condition(element))
            return element;
        var subElement = FindFirstDescendant(element, condition);
        if (subElement != null)
            return subElement;
        element = walker.GetNextSibling(element);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: FindDescendant doesn't seem to be defined

Comment: @John Smith, I updated the answer, the name was renamed to FindFirstDescendant.

Answer (score 3):

[As the documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.propertyconditionflags.aspx), you can ask for a case-insensitive comparison. There is no "regular expression" flag. You will have to do the filtering manually.

Comment: I thought this might be the case - Thank you for clarifying!