# How do you get the Microsoft Coded UI Test Builder to recognize an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I created a small WPF application (just to explore how Coded UI Testing works). My application contained an `ItemsControl`, but the Coded UI Test Builder UIMap could not find the appropriate control.

**XAML**:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers, Mode=OneTime}"
              AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CustomersItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{Binding Path=Id, StringFormat='Customer_{0}', Mode=OneWay}"
                       Margin="5">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{1}, {0}">
                        <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                        <Binding Path="LastName" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The problem that I have is that even though WPF has an [`ItemsControlAutomationPeer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.itemscontrolautomationpeer(v=vs.110).aspx), the Coded UI Test Builder cannot locate the control to be added to the UIMap. The only way I got around it was by getting the root AutomationElement, then utilizing the `TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker` (I used the code found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19410808/347172)), however that solution doesn't give me access to the control itself, just the `AutomationElement`. Ideally, since there is an AutomationPeer for the control, I was wondering if there was a better way to get at this control (even if it is impossible to get to for the UIMap).

---

Also, a side note. I understand already that Visual Studio ignores `TextBlock`s when doing Coded UI Testing because there can be so many produced. Right now I'm more concerned with getting to the `ItemsControl` itself, not the individual `TextBlock`s that are generated from within it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging a bit into this issue, I found a semi-solution. I looked at how the `UIMap` designer files generate their code for a `ListView` (I adjusted the code a bit for my own variables):

```
var itemscontrol = new WpfList(window);
itemscontrol.SearchProperties[WpfList.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "CustomersItemsControl";
itemscontrol.WindowTitles.Add("MainWindow");

var count = itemscontrol.Items.Count(); // Returns the correct value!
```

I copied this code and it seems to work for an `ItemsControl` as well, at least some properties do, such as [`WpfList.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.wpfcontrols.wpflist.items.aspx). So, it's a partial solution I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The ItemsControl and TextBlock don't have the AutomationPeer inside.
The [ItemsControlAutomationPeer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.itemscontrolautomationpeer(v=vs.110).aspx) is an abstract class.
Here's one of the solutions to find the items, not the ItemsControl itself: [WPF ItemsControl with TestStack White](http://abusanad.net/2016/12/19/wpf-itemscontrol-with-teststack-white/).